# Using Linq to get Sum of all items in Group except first item?

Tags: c#, linq

I want to get *sum* of all student's `FeesUnpaid` *except* the *first student* in *each group*.

**Expected Output**

```
1770 == (400 + 350 + 100 + 20 + 900)
```

**What I tried**

```
int result = StudentsList
  .Select(x => x.FeesUnpaid)
  .FirstOrDefault()
  .Sum();
```

I have **compile time error**:

> Compilation error: 'int' does not contain a definition for 'Sum' and
>   the best extension method overload
>   'System.Linq.Queryable.Sum(System.Linq.IQueryable)' has some
>   invalid arguments

**My Code-**

```
public class StudentInfo
{
  public string Student { get; set; }
  public string University { get; set; }
  public int GroupID { get; set; }
  public int FeesUnpaid {get; set;}
}

List<StudentInfo> StudentsList = new List<StudentInfo>();

// Group 1
StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="John", University="ABC", GroupID = 1, FeesUnpaid= 200});
StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Jack", University="DEF", GroupID = 1, FeesUnpaid= 400} );
StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Peter", University="GHI", GroupID = 1, FeesUnpaid= 0} );

// Group 2
StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Donald", University="JKL", GroupID = 2, FeesUnpaid= 0} );
StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Olivia", University="ABC", GroupID = 2, FeesUnpaid= 350} );

// Group 3
StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Emity", University="OPQ", GroupID = 3, FeesUnpaid= 40} );
StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Emma", University="GHI", GroupID = 3, FeesUnpaid= 100} );

// Group 4
StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Alan", University="DEF", GroupID = 4, FeesUnpaid= 50} );
StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Alan", University="DEF", GroupID = 4, FeesUnpaid= 20} );

// Group 5
StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Adam", University="GHI", GroupID = 5, FeesUnpaid= 400} );
StudentsList.Add( new StudentInfo { Student="Matthew", University="OPQ", GroupID = 5, FeesUnpaid= 900} );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can `GroupBy` and then `Skip(1)` within each group:

```
List<StudentInfo> StudentsList = ...

...

var result = Students
  .GroupBy(student => student.GroupID)  // Combine students into Groups
  .SelectMany(group => group.Skip(1))   // Skip 1st student in each group and flatten groups
  .Sum(student => student.FeesUnpaid);  // finally, sum FeesUnpaid
```

Answer (score 0):

`StudentsList.Select((x=> x.FeesUnpaid)).FirstOrDefault()` will return the first `FeesUnpaid` value i.e. 200, so you can't `Sum()` that.

```
int result = StudentsList
    .GroupBy(s => s.GroupID) // Create groups
    .Select(grp => grp.Skip(1).Sum(s => s.FeesUnpaid)) // Get total fees unpaid, except the firs in each group
    .Sum(); // Get a total sum
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
int result = StudentsList.GroupBy(s => s.GroupID).Select(g => g.Skip(1).Sum(x => x.FeesUnpaid)).Sum();
```